# Is it valid to generalize a dataset across different categories using a non-linear transformation?

Tags: data-transformation

I am researching a gender pay gap, but my data includes companies in a few different countries. The wage norms are vastly different in these countries, and I'm trying to figure out a way to "even out" the data while still keeping the distributions within countries the same. I have tried normalising the data within each country by using the country's mean and standard deviation, but this changes the gaps within the countries (from say 5% to 200%, as the numbers become so small). Then I figured that, to keep the gaps the same within the countries, each value must be divided by a single ratio. I used the ratio of $\frac{\bar{x}_{country}}{\bar{x}_{overall}}$. This makes it so each country has the same mean (the overall mean) while the gender pay gap within the countries are kept the same as with the original data. However, as it isn't a linear transformation, the distributions are transformed. I'm having trouble figuring out if it's fair to calculate a "transformed" gap using this transformation, as higher values are more heavily penalised than lower values.

The gender pay gap is calculated as follows: $$\frac{\bar{x}_{men} - \bar{x}_{women}}{\bar{x}_{men}}$$

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or is there a better transformation I'm not thinking of? Or is this actually okay to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "normalize" you really mean standardize.  If you normalized within each country, the range of values would be [0,1] within each country.  Normalized x-values are defined as

$x_i=\frac{x_i-\min(x)}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$,

where $\min(x)$ and $\max(x)$ are the min and max values within a country.

You could also calculate percentiles within each country, whose range would be [0,1] within each country. Percentiles are

$PCT_i=\frac{R(x_i)}{(n+1)}$,

where $R(x_i)$ is the rank of $x_i$ within the country, and $n$ is the number of values for the same country.

Comment: You're right! I always mess up standardize and normalize... Thanks for your ideas! I'll have a think on them

Comment: Pls accept as answer, as moderators don't like a lost of OPs that sit without an accepted answer.